# How to trim string till first alphabet in a alphanumeric string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a alpha numeric string as `24 minutes` i want to trim it like `24m`please tell me how can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try use code in regex:

```
NSString *string = @"24 minutes";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]{1}).*" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"$1$2"];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

output:

```
24m
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `componentsSeparatedByString:` and `substringToIndex:` methods of [NSString Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/), to achieve the result.

```
NSString *str       = @"24 minutes";
NSArray *components = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

// Validation to prevent array out of index crash (If input is 24)
if ([components count] >= 2)
{
    NSString *secondStr = components[1];
    // Validation to prevent crash (If input is 24 )
    if (secondStr.length)
    {
        NSString *shortName = [secondStr substringToIndex:1];
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",components[0],shortName];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

This example works with the above string, however you need to take care of different type of inputs. It can fail if there is multiple spaces between those values.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *aString = @"24 minutes"; // can be "1 minute" also.
```

First divide the string into two components:
Divide it with white space, since your string can contain one or more number also like "1 minute", "24 mintutes".

```
    NSArray *array = [aString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    array = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"]];

    NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Then fetch the first letter of the second component of the string using  `substringToIndex` and finally combine both the strings.

```
    NSString * firstLetter = [[array objectAtIndex:1] substringToIndex:1];

    NSString *finalString = [[array objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:firstLetter];

    NSLog(@"%@",finalString);
```